# Laravel Route 'posts/savedPosts' Returns Not Found Error

Tags: php, laravel

Issue Overview:
I am encountering a "not found" error when attempting to access the route '/posts/savedPosts'. Despite my efforts, I haven't been able to pinpoint the root cause of the problem.

**this is my web.php**

```
Route::get("/posts/saves",[SaveController::class, "savedPosts"])->middleware("auth");
```

**this my SaveController**

```
    //Saved the post
    public function savePost(Post $post)
    {


        // Check if the user has saved the specified post
        $isSaved = auth()->user()->saves()->where('post_id', $post->id)->exists();

        if ($isSaved) {
            // Detach the specified post from the user's saves
            auth()->user()->saves()->delete($post->id);

            return redirect()->back();
        } else {
            // Save the post for the authenticated user
            auth()->user()->saves()->create(['post_id' => $post->id]);
            return redirect()->back()->with("message", "Post saved successfully");
        }
    }


    //Show All the Saved Posts
    public function savedPosts()
    {

        // Get All the posts for the  current authenticated user
        $posts = auth()->user()->saves();

        dd($posts);
        return view("posts", ["posts" => $posts]);
    }
```

**i did try this but nothing worked out :C**

```
Route::get("/posts/saves", function () {
    return "Hello, World!";
});
```

Comment: From the code you shared, the pinpoint for this error is that you don't have a `Route::get('/posts/savedPosts', ...)` Route defined... Do you? You only show a `/test` Route... Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77841680/edit) to include your _actual_ routes, and the full error.

Comment: i edited now ,but still give me error 404 not found

Comment: You need to clarify _which_ URL is giving your a 404. If you define `Route::get('/posts/saves', ...)`, but you're navigating to `http://localhost:8000/posts/savedPosts`, then **of course you will get a 404**. You need to navigate to `http://localhost:8000/posts/saves`, aka **the Route you've actually defined**. Please read the documentation on how Routes work: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/routing. This is a very simple and basic concept.

Comment: @TimLewis sorry i was so bad ,i edit my question and actually that still give me an error 404 not found

Comment: *"that still give me an error 404"* - **WHAT** gives you a 404? Once again, you haven't shared the URL you're navigating to that is triggering this 404. What is the URL in your browser when you get this error? If you can't share that information after being asked multiple times, we really cannot help you.

Comment: @TimLewis, the problem is that when I navigate to '/posts/saves', I expect the SavedPosts method in my SaveController to return the view. However, it gives a 404 error instead.

Comment: If `Route::get('/posts/saves', ...)` is the only defined route in `routes/web.php`, then that shouldn't be happening. You may have a wildcard Route, like `/posts/{post}` that is triggering instead. Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77841680/edit) and include any other `/posts` Routes (and I mean **edit** your question. **Please do not post a new question this time**)

Comment: @TimLewis, thank you, bro, for taking the time to answer me. As you mentioned earlier, the issue was that I had defined my route after the '/posts/{post}' route. After changing the order, the route worked fine. I don't understand why that happened?

Comment: Because `/posts/{post}` is a wildcard, intended to function with routes like `/posts/1`. `1` is an ID from your database, so it finds an associated record. Since you defined your routes the wrong order, when you navigated to `/posts/saves`, the wildcard matched that Route, but you don't have a record with an ID of `saves` in your database, so it triggers a 404 error. So yeah, as long as define the explicit one `/posts/saves` **before** your wildcard one `/posts/{post}`, your code should work.